# /usr/local/bin/node: Undefined symbol "nghttp2_option_set_max_settings" erro when i try to run node in freebsd

Tags: node.js, npm, freebsd

i have install node and npm from freebsd repositries, but when i try to check the version or try to use node or npm i get following error.

```
/usr/local/bin/node: Undefined symbol "nghttp2_option_set_max_settings"
```

i tried to open this file but the file is encrypted :'(.

Comment: Since nghttp2 is not part of either npm or node, something else is going on here. I don't get this error myself.

Comment: as i am newbie in this i dont knw whats the reason for this error....

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=241643

Try running `pkg update -f` and then `pkg install -f node libnghttp2`.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i tried this but still same error :'(.

Comment: What FreeBSD version are you running?

Comment: FreeBSD 11.3-STABLE amd64

Comment: 11.3 is not supported anymore, so package repositories for this version aren't updated anymore. So you were right to update the system.